# A question about the concept of the time

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

1. $\delta[n+1]$ equals to one only $n+1 = 0$ ?
2. If the 1. is true, so what does a signal $x[n+1] $ stand for? Is this signal causal or anticausal? I mean, if 1. is true, $n = -1$, so is this signal causal? (because it just happens before the time I want). But Oppenheim says that it is anticausal. Why?

Comment: Signals cannot be causal or anti-causal, only systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A discrete signal can be defined at different integer time indices. Generally, one talks about causal or anticausal systems. But since a signal can, when convolved, be interpreted as a system, some say that:

> Causal signals are signals that are zero for all negative time, while
>   anticausal are signals that are zero for all positive time.

You can read that in the [Classification of signals](https://cnx.org/contents/l-e_wSqM@24/Signal-Classifications-and-Pro). Accordingly to that definition, your signal would be anticausal. Oppenheim sounds correct. One interpretation is: if you convolve a signal $x$ by an anticausal signal, the result will start "sooner" that $x$, a breach in causality.

Comment: Oh, it seems that anticausal is absolutely noncausal. I say a wrong concept.. What does $x[n+1]$ stand for? It is the signal 1s before or after the original signal?

Comment: If you have $x$, and write $y[n] = x[n+1]$, then $x[n+1]$ is $1$ when $n=-1$, so $y[-1] =1$, before the original.

Comment: **This system is not causal, since the current value of the output depends on a future value of the input. ** This sentence is copied from Oppnhiem. He says that $x[n+1]$ is the future value. It seems so weird..

Comment: Exactly, because to get $y[-1]$ you need $x[0]$, a future value regarding index $-1$

Answer (score 0):

The signal $x(n+1)$ just means that it is a signal based on $x(n)$ but with the samples at other time instances, in particular, all the samples are at the previous time instance.
For example, the value that $x(n)$ had at $n=0$, now would be at $n=-1$, because to obtain $x(0)$ with the new signal $x(n+1)$ you have to put the time index $n=-1$, so that $x(-1+1) = x(0)$.

Based on the definition that was given in Laurent Duval's answer, if your signal had a non zero value at $n=0$ then after the shift it would become non causal.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What you mean is that the signal is based on a stanard original time$( t= 0)$. Is it right? $x(n+1)$ stands for the time before original signal?

Comment: I wouldn't call it original time, but sure if it makes you understand it better. It just means that $x(n+1)$ is the same signal (same shape and values of the samples) but all samples are shifted to the LEFT in the time axis.